# af:query issues selects for each row and each LOV when searching

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a sql based viewObject like this (more columns than here) with LOVs, which I  want to query

```
   SELECT 
        SAS_MARKS_NEW_V.MARK MARK, 
        SAS_MARKS_NEW_V.PASS PASS, 
        SAS_MARKS_NEW_V.SEAS_ID SEAS_ID, 
        SAS_MARKS_NEW_V.STUD_ID STUD_ID, 
    FROM 
        SAS_MARKS_NEW_V
```

Fields ending with _ID are not shown in the UI and have list of values attached to them. View accessors are fairy tuned (I don't use shared AM instance, but set RowLevelBinds false and SharedVOInstance true). To the page I dropped af:query with table. This page loads decent (with few selectOneChoice and ComboWithLov), but when I select some values from lov and hit search, it takes a while. Using logger in finest level i saw that searching (even if no rows are found)  multiple LOV select queries are executed:

```
    <ADFLogger> <begin> Get LOV list
    <ADFLogger> <begin> Get LOV list
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Get LOV list
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Get LOV list
    <ADFLogger> <end> Get LOV list
    <ADFLogger> <end> Get LOV list
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <execute> [2416] _LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1 ViewRowSetImpl.execute caused params to be "un"changed
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <execute> [2416] _LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1 ViewRowSetImpl.execute caused params to be "un"changed
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <initQueryCollection> [2417] Carrying over CappedRowCount:-1for ViewRowSet:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <initQueryCollection> [2417] Carrying over CappedRowCount:-1for ViewRowSet:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <QueryCollection> <createColumnList> [2418] Column count: 3
    <QueryCollection> <createColumnList> [2418] Column count: 3
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <execute> [2419] executeQueryForCollection ViewObject:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1, RowSet:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <ViewRowSetImpl> <execute> [2419] executeQueryForCollection ViewObject:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1, RowSet:_LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <ADFLogger> <begin> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <begin> Execute query
    <ViewObjectImpl> <buildQuery> [2420] _LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1>#q old SQLStmtBufLen: 165, actual=135, storing=165
    <ViewObjectImpl> <buildQuery> [2420] _LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1>#q old SQLStmtBufLen: 165, actual=135, storing=165
    <ViewObjectImpl> <buildQuery> [2421] SELECT 
    GROU_TYPE_V.CLVA_ID CLVA_ID, 
    GROU_TYPE_V.CODE CODE, 
    GROU_TYPE_V.TITLE TITLE 
    FROM 
    CL_GROU_TYPE_V GROU_TYPE_V
    <ViewObjectImpl> <buildQuery> [2421] SELECT 
    GROU_TYPE_V.CLVA_ID CLVA_ID, 
    GROU_TYPE_V.CODE CODE, 
    GROU_TYPE_V.TITLE TITLE 
    FROM 
    CL_GROU_TYPE_V GROU_TYPE_V
    <ViewObjectImpl> <getStatementFromCache> [2422] ViewObject: [com.innodea.sas.model.lovs.views.GrouTypeLOVVO]MarksAM._LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1 Reusing defined prepared Statement
    <ViewObjectImpl> <getStatementFromCache> [2422] ViewObject: [com.innodea.sas.model.lovs.views.GrouTypeLOVVO]MarksAM._LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1 Reusing defined prepared Statement
    <ViewObjectImpl> <bindParametersForCollection> [2423] Bind params for ViewObject: [com.innodea.sas.model.lovs.views.GrouTypeLOVVO]MarksAM._LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <ViewObjectImpl> <bindParametersForCollection> [2423] Bind params for ViewObject: [com.innodea.sas.model.lovs.views.GrouTypeLOVVO]MarksAM._LOCAL_VIEW_USAGE_internal_vcival_def_GrouTypeLOVVO1
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <addContextData> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <end> Execute query
    <ADFLogger> <end> Execute query
```

Does this mean that for every returned row a lov sql is issued to set viewAccessors? 
Can i speed up query somehow? 
DoviewObjects with lov values can't be used effectively with default af:query?

Comment: Are your queries called upon in the getters/setters? ADF likes to call getters/setters multiple times, making it extremely bad form to have any kind of logic in them.

Answer (score 0):

I was using view objects from outside my application module and they were not contained in shared application module. This resulted in new row sets for every row. Here is in detail: http://withice.blogspot.com/2014/06/tiuning-list-of-values-in-viewobject.html